# Create a batch file to create a CSV only containing the names of the newest file and date within multiple folders

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have managed to find a handful of scripts to allow me to create a csv that contains all files within a directory and it's sub directories, only pulling specific file types (.pdf for my tests) and sort them by the most recent modified date. However I can not find a way to cut the list down to only the most recently modified file from each folder.

For instance lets say I have folder "A" and in folder "A" I have folders "1-5" I would like to be able to look into each of the folders 1-5, note which files is the most recently modified and report to a csv with the information as such

| File path | Filename | Date Modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C:\A\1 | Name.pdf | 7/29/2022 |
| C:\A\2 | Other.pdf | 5/10/2021 |

Some of the batch scripts I have been able to find and work through are below but I haven't been able to combine them in any meaningful way.

`for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i echo The most recently created file is %LAST% pause`

and

````
(FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir *.pdf /s /o-d /b /a-d') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3*" %%x IN ('dir /a-d /tc "%%~a"^|findstr "^[0-9]"') DO (
        ECHO "%%a",%%~ta,%%x %%y %%z
    )
))>DIR.csv
TYPE DIR.csv```
````

Comment: What you've shown is a particular software's representaion of CSV data file content. The most common CSV format would look like this; Header Record: ```"File path","Filename","Date Modified"```, Data Record 1: ```"C:\A\1","Name.pdf","7/29/2022"```, Data Record 2: ```"C:\A\2","Other.pdf","5/10/2021"```. Although the following alternative is in common use too; Header Record: ```File path,Filename,Date Modified```, Data Record 1: ```C:\A\1,Name.pdf,7/29/2022```, Data Record 2: ```C:\A\2,Other.pdf,5/10/2021```. We would also need to know which value separator character your software accepts.

Comment: I was just using the table from stack overflow as an easy to read format. Just using excel to read the CSVs after they have been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create the file with the header
> DIRS.csv (
echo File path,Filename,Date Modified

rem Process each folder in this directory
for /D %%d in (*) do (
   cd "%%d"

   rem Get filePath, fileName and dateMod of all files in mod date order
   rem and keep the data of the last one
   for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W *.*') do (
      set "filePath=%%~DPf"
      set "fileName=%%~NXf"
      set "dateMod=%%~Tf"
   )

   rem Show they
   for /F %%a in ("!dateMod!") do echo !filePath!,!fileName!,%%a

   rem Pass to next folder
   cd ..

)
)
```

Comment: That worked almost perfectly. Is there a way to add a line so it can check sub directories as well? Say folder A contains folders AA-FF and it needs to check in each folder for the newest file within AA-FF.

Comment: If you think my answer is useful to you, may I ask you to upvote it at least? Better yet, select it as best answer...

Comment: I can mark it as the answer, but it doesn't let me upvote it. I had just made this account.

"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

rem switch to specified directory

PUSHD "%~1"

(
ECHO File path,Filename,Date Modified

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /ad /b') DO (
 SET "first=Y"
 FOR /f %%o IN ('dir /b /o-d /a-d "%%~fe\*.bat" 2^>nul') DO (
  FOR /f %%b IN ('dir /o-d /a-d "%%~fe\*.bat" 2^>nul^|find "/" ') DO IF DEFINED first (
   SET "first="
   ECHO %cd%\%%e,%%~nxo,%%b
  )
 )
)
)>"reportfilename.csv"

popd

GOTO :EOF
```

First switch to the directoryname specified as the first parameter. If that directoryname contains separators, it needs to be `"quoted"`. If no parameter is supplied, current directory.

Output the header line

Get each subdirectory name to `%%e` in turn.

Set the `first` flag and assign the name of each file matching the filemask (I used `*.bat`) in turn to `%%o` The `/o-d` switch provides the names in reverse-last-update-datestamp order.

Then do a conventional `dir` using the same sort criterion and pick the first token (date) of the first line containing `/` to `%%b`.

If `first` is set to any value, set it to *nothing* so that it is no longer defined and output the directory name, filename and date as required.